# Does the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-|x|} \ dx $ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Since we are in $(-\infty,0]$, it means that $|x|=-x$. So the integrand should be $e^{-(-x)}=e^x.$ Now;

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow-\infty}\int_{n}^{0} e^x\ dx= \lim_{n\rightarrow-\infty}(e^0-e^n) =1-0=1. $$

Is this reasoning correct or is the correct answer just accidental?

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: It is correct and complete. And if you integrate also from $0$ to $+\infty$, the absolute value becomes important and the integral converges there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is correct and the reasoning is too. One line you could add is

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} (e^0) - \lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} (e^n)
$$
to show it more clearly. 
Then 
$$=1 - \lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} (e^n)
$$
$$=1 - 0 
$$
$$=1 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct and so is the argument. The notation is a bit awkward, however. Why $n$? It is usually used for integers.

Comment: Abuse the letter $n$ with this improper integral: $\int_{-\infty}^0 \cos 2\pi x \ dx$

Comment: I have seen many questions to calculate limit and the variable of limit is $n \to \infty$

Comment: I don't see how this is abuse. You can choose the sequence $\{e^{-n}\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}},$ and observe that the sequence $e^{-n}\to 0$ to argue that this converges, since $e^{-|x|}$ is monotonically decreasing.